# Espress - Accessing nth child element of linear layout

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

In espresso i am trying to access 3rd child element of linear layout.
see attached screenshot.

[image]

i tried some matcher, but not get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom matcher:

```
 public static Matcher<View> nthChildOf(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int childPosition) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
      @Override
      public void describeTo(Description description) {
        description.appendText("with "+childPosition+" child view of type parentMatcher");
      }

      @Override
      public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
        if (!(view.getParent() instanceof ViewGroup)) {
              return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent());
        }

        ViewGroup group = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        return parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent()) && group.getChildAt(childPosition).equals(view);
      }
    };
  }
```

To use it:

```
onView(nthChildOf(withId(R.id.directParentLinearLayout), 0).check(matches(withText("I am the first child"));
```

In your case you also need to check that is descendant of the layout that has the unique id:

```
onView(nthChildOf(allOf(withId(R.id.directParentLinearLayout), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.linearLayoutWithUniqueId))), 0).check(matches(withText("I am the first child"));
```